# How do I register collisions with objects from the same class without an unwanted object from another class in my group?

Tags: python, pygame

The goal is to set the value of `Touch` to True whenever player1 and player2 (P1 and P2) collide, without it happening whenever any of the players touch a wall.
Note: Setting `Touch` to True works in the block_hit_list collision set but i've commented it out as I tried to get it working without the walls.
Any help would be very appreciated.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    global Touch
```

```
#  Creating lists of objects (self.walls/ all_sprites) for later use but ensuring their values don't interfere
        P_LIST = None
        
        self.walls = None
        self.all_sprites = None
        #  Creating objects (self.walls/ all_sprites) for later use but ensuring their values don't interfere
        self.P1 = None
        self.P2 = None
```

Where collisions are registered. the variables apple and seed were temporary and involved with me testing my own method

```
def update(self):
        global Touch
        # Move left/right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        apple = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, P_LIST, False)
        for seed in apple:
            if seed != self:
                Touch = True
 
        #  Did this update cause us to hit a wall?
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.all_sprites, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if block != self:
                #Touch = True
                #time.sleep(0.1)
                #Touch = False
            #  If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
                if self.change_x > 0:
                    self.rect.right = block.rect.left

                else:
                #  Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                    self.rect.left = block.rect.right
            
 
        #  Collisons on the y-axis
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        apple = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, P_LIST, False)
        for seed in apple:
            if seed != self:
                Touch = True
 
        #  Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.all_sprites, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if block != self:
            #  Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
                if self.change_y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top

                else:
                    self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
```

Everything past this point is outside of the Player class

```
all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
P_LIST = all_sprite_list.copy()
```

```
#  Create the player paddle object
P2 = Player(400, 400, RED)
P1 = Player(600, 400, WHITE)

#  Wall interaction
P1.walls = wall_list
P2.walls = wall_list

#  Adding the players to the list of sprites
all_sprite_list.add(P1)
all_sprite_list.add(P2)

#  Assigns the attribute all_sprites all_sprites_list for the players
P1.all_sprites = all_sprite_list
P2.all_sprites = all_sprite_list

#  Attempting to remove (walls form the list) i'm not even sure if any of these are the correct version
P_LIST.remove(P1.walls)
P_LIST.remove(P2.walls)
P_LIST.remove(wall)
P_LIST.remove(wall_list)
```

Here is the wall class with an example of an object created from it:

```
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Constructor function
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        # Make a blue wall, of the size specified in the parameters
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(HASTEBLUE)
 
        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

wall = Wall(BaseX, 150, MAP_WIDTH, WALL_THICKNESS)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to detect if 2 [`pygame.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) objects are colliding, then you can use [`pygame.sprite.collide_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect). For instance:

```py
Touch = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(P1, P2)
if Touch:
    print("P1 and P2 have collided")
```